# op amp compensation with C or RC

Tags: operational-amplifier

In reading about op-amp compensation I came across two variants of compensation. Sometimes the compensation is done with a simple capacitor. And sometimes a rc as shown in the figure below (r1 and C1).

So, the capacitor is used to roll off the frequency response for stability reasons.
What effect could the resistor in series have?
To me the resistor seems rather useless.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single capacitor is often used to provide dominant pole compensation. This pole ensures that the open loop gain falls away with a phase shift of less than 180 degrees at the point where the loop gain is unity. The resistor results in a zero in the open loop response, which can still ensure stability while offering a wider bandwidth. The zero can effectively cancel a pole.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve's answer states, a single capacitor allows you to have a dominant pole compensation and the resistor adds a zero to the response. This can be used to reduce the added phase shift at higher frequencies, cancelling some of the effect of the compensation to ensure stability at higher frequencies and thus enabling a wider bandwidth. This would be the main purpose on bipolar OpAmps such as the LM790C.

In the case of FET amplifiers, the introduction of a miller compensation capacitance is likely to lead to a right-hand zero that can cause stability problems with any additional feedback. The introduction of a resistor moves this zero to the left-hand of the s plane.

Comment: probably meant UA709